# Syntax shorthand for updating only changed rows in UPSERT

Tags: postgresql, update, syntax, upsert

I have a query which upserts into Postgres when a key conflicts only if there are changes to one of the other columns (to avoid unnecessary inserts and returned rows where nothing was actually changed):

```
INSERT INTO public.test_upsert (some_id, a, b, note) 
VALUES 
  ('c', 1, true, 'asdf')
ON CONFLICT (some_id)
DO UPDATE SET 
  a = excluded.a, 
  b = excluded.b, 
  note = excluded.note 
WHERE
  test_upsert.a IS DISTINCT FROM excluded.a OR 
  test_upsert.b IS DISTINCT FROM excluded.b OR
  test_upsert.note IS DISTINCT FROM excluded.note
RETURNING *;
```

My question is: is there shorthand for this? I basically want to either insert a new record update the rows when any of the columns being inserted are distinct from the existing columns. Writing out each column individually gets quite verbose, although it is more explicit.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no provision in SQL to say *"all columns except this one"*. (You can do something like that with `jsonb` or `hstore`.) Related answer with details:

- [Select columns inside json_agg](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69655/select-columns-inside-json-agg/69658#69658)

**On second thought**, you don't need this. You might as well update *all* columns. Postgres writes a new row version anyway, nothing lost.

```
INSERT INTO test_upsert AS t (some_id, a, b, note)  -- list is optional
VALUES ('c', 5, true, 'asdf')
ON     CONFLICT (some_id)
DO     UPDATE
SET    (some_id, a, b, note) = ROW (excluded.*)  -- ROW syntax
WHERE  (t.*) IS DISTINCT FROM (excluded.*)       -- again, compare whole row
RETURNING *;
```

You still have to spell out the column list *once* for the target list of `SET`. That's required. The rest can be shortened.

You might even omit the target list for the `INSERT` while targeting all columns anyway, but in most cases it's good form to spell it out, more robust against future changes.

`excluded` represents the **whole** row proposed for insertion. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT)

> Note that the effects of all per-row `BEFORE INSERT` triggers are
> reflected in `excluded` values, since those effects may have
> contributed to the row being excluded from insertion.

Columns that were not targeted explicitly (or in `BEFORE INSERT` triggers) hold their respective **`DEFAULT`** values (`NULL` being the default `DEFAULT`). You may need special treatment for `serial` or `IDENTITY` columns.

The **table alias** is an optional additional syntax shorthand. Note that the `AS` key word is required for a table alias for the target of an `INSERT` - unlike most places for a table alias.

- [The manual on `INSERT`.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html)

Or even shorter, yet:

```
...
WHERE  t IS DISTINCT FROM excluded
...
```

We can as well just use the table name (or alias) for the (well-known!) composite type. The only corner-case disadvantage of this: if there is also a column of the same name "t" (or "excluded"), it takes precedence due to Postgres syntax rules. `(t.*) IS DISTINCT FROM (excluded.*)` cannot be mistaken and is the slightly safer form. Related answer:

- [Convert a row to a nested JSON document containing all relations](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/247241/convert-a-row-to-a-nested-json-document-containing-all-relations/248834#248834)

Comment: This is amazing!  Thanks!  Much more succinct yet still explicit as to what's happening. :-)  Having to type the columns twice instead of 5 times will save my fingers a lot of strain since I have to do this for a number of tables. :D

Comment: @Caustic: While inserting to all (or leading) columns, you *might* even omit the target list of `INSERT`, too. Typically, it's better to be explicit there, though.

Comment: Thanks, @ErwinBrandstetter ! Reason to specify which columns are updated: a trigger `BEFORE UPDATE OF note ON table` shouldn't trigger if `note` didn't change

Comment: @Marius: Be aware that this clause only demands the column be mentioned as target. To make sure it actually changed, add a `WHEN` clause. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18360493/939860